# Kubernetes - pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset, persistent-volume-claims

I'm using mysql Kubernetes statefulset, i mapped PVs to host directory (CentOS 8 VM) but getting " pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims"

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql-container
spec:
  serviceName: mysql
  replicas: 1 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql-container
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql-container
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql-container
        image: mysql:dev
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
             name: prod-secrets
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
         # container (pod) path
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mysql-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql


      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: mysql-pvc
 volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
      spec:

        storageClassName: localstorage
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 3Gi
        selector:
           matchLabels:
            type: local
```

Storage class is defaulr and no events in PV

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:

  name: localstorage

provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
reclaimPolicy: Delete
allowVolumeExpansion: True


kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysql-01
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: localstorage
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/mysql01"

---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysql-02
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: localstorage
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/mysql02"
```

Storage class is default one

```
get sc
NAME                     PROVISIONER                    RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
localstorage (default)   kubernetes.io/no-provisioner   Delete          Immediate           true                   35m
```

PVC also shows no events:

```
    Name:          data-mysql-0
    Namespace:     default
    StorageClass:  localstorage
    Status:        Pending
    Volume:        mysql-storage
    Labels:        app=mysql
    Annotations:   <none>
    Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
    Capacity:      0
    Access Modes:
    VolumeMode:    Filesystem
    Mounted By:    mysql-0
    Events:        <none>


Name:            mysql-01
Labels:          type=local
Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                   {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolume","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"type":"local"},"name":"mysql-01"},"spec":{"accessMode...
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    localstorage
Status:          Available
Claim:
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        10Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /mnt/mysql01
    HostPathType:
Events:            <none>


Name:            mysql-02
Labels:          type=local
Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                   {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolume","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"type":"local"},"name":"mysql-02"},"spec":{"accessMode...
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    localstorage
Status:          Available
Claim:
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        10Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /mnt/mysql02
    HostPathType:
Events:            <none>
```

Pod is in pending state:

```
>       Events:
>          Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
>          ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
>          Warning  FailedScheduling  27s (x2 over 27s)  default-scheduler  error while running >"VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "mysql-0": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
```

> Can someone point out what else should be done here, thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`PersistentVolumeClaims` will remain unbound indefinitely if a matching `PersistentVolume` does not exist. The `PersistentVolume` is matched with `accessModes` and `capacity`. In this case `capacity` the PV is `10Gi` whereas PVC has `capacity` of `3Gi`.

The `capacity` in the PV needs to same as in the claim i.e `3Gi` to fix the `unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims` issue.

Answer (score 20):

The error can be caused by multiple reasons - below are a few of them.

---

**Example 1**

The `persistentvolume-controller` has failed to find a `PV` with a capacity **greater or equal** than the value specified in the `PVC`.

For example:

```
  # PVC
  resources:
     requests:
       storage: 3Gi


  # PV
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
```

So: 
If  `PV capacity >= PVC capacity` then the PVC should be able to bound to the PV.

If not then we'll get the `unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims` error in `Pod` logs and `no volume plugin matched name` when describing the PVC.

---

**Example 2**

The number of PVCs exceeds the number of available PVs.

For example if only one PV has been created (or the others were deleted):

```
$ kubectl get pv
NAME             CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                      STORAGECLASS    REASON   AGE
mongo-local-pv   50Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/mongo-persistent-storage-mongo-0   local-storage            106m
```

We could see that some workloads (`Pods` or `StatefulSets`) will be stuck in the `Pending` state:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongo-0   2/2     Running   0          3m38s
mongo-1   0/2     Pending   0          3m23s

$ kubectl get pvc
NAME                               STATUS    VOLUME           CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS    AGE
mongo-persistent-storage-mongo-0   Bound     mongo-local-pv   50Gi       RWO            local-storage   80m
mongo-persistent-storage-mongo-1   Pending                                              local-storage   45m
```

and we will get the OP's error (unbound [immediate] `PersistentVolumeClaims`).

---

**Example 3**

If the scheduler failed to find a node with a matching label for the PV.

When using **local volumes** the `nodeAffinity` of the PV **is required** and should be a value of a node available in the cluster:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-mongo-pv
  .
  .
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node-which-does-not-exists  # <----- Will lead to an error
```

---

**Example 4**

A `PV` with the same name but a different configuration already exists in the cluster and the new `PVC` is created according to them.

**When working with local volumes the administrator must perform a manual clean-up** and set up the local volumes again each time for reuse.

(*) [This](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner) local static provisioner was created to help with the PV lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. It would be great to have also suggestions on how to solve such PVC problems.